# Adding a chatbot in Socket.io basic chat application

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, chat, chatbot

I want to integrate a chatbot that should be connected to any user who is waiting to be connected to a real human user. The chatbot will entertain the user by responding the human user messages.

A similar chatbot has been implemented here named "Didianer.com", if you go here and start typing you will see him responding.

http://socket.io/demos/chat/

I want the exact same bot in my application too but I am totally lost on where to start.

Here is my server side code

```
  //Server receives a new message (in data var) from the client.
   socket.on('message', function (data) {
      var room = rooms[socket.id];
      //Server sends the message to the user in room
      socket.broadcast.to(room).emit('new message', {
      username: socket.username,
      message: data
    });
 });


 // when the client emits 'add user', this listens and executes (When user enters ENTER)
  socket.on('add user', function (username) {
    if (addedUser) return;
//Own
names[socket.id] = username;//save username in array
allUsers[socket.id] = socket; // add current user to all users array


// we store the username in the socket session for this client
socket.username = username;
++numUsers;
addedUser = true;
socket.emit('login', {
  numUsers: numUsers
});
// echo globally (all clients) that a person has connected
socket.broadcast.emit('user joined', {
  username: socket.username,
  numUsers: numUsers
});

 // now check if sb is in queue
findPeerForLoneSocket(socket);
  });
```

FindPeerforLoneSocket is called when a new user connects and wants to talk to someone else. Here I am assuming the logic for bot should go. Such as if the user is waiting (in queue) for 5 seconds and nobody is online to talk, then connect the user (add the user and the chatbot) in one room so they both can can start talking. I am not sure how to respond to chat events and how chat bot will reply...

```
 var findPeerForLoneSocket = function(socket) {
  console.log("i am in finding a peer");

// this is place for possibly some extensive logic
// which can involve preventing two people pairing multiple times

if (queue.length>0) {
          console.log("people are online" + queue.length);


    // somebody is in queue, pair them!
    var peer = queue.pop();
    var room = socket.id + '#' + peer.id;
    var str = socket.id;

    // join them both
    peer.join(room);
    socket.join(room);
    // register rooms to their names
    rooms[peer.id] = room;
    rooms[socket.id] = room;
    // exchange names between the two of them and start the chat
    peer.emit('chat start', {'name': names[socket.id], 'room':room});
    socket.emit('chat start', {'name': names[peer.id], 'room':room});

    //Remove backslash from socketid
//  str = socket.id.replace('/#', '-');



} else {
    // queue is empty, add our lone socket
    queue.push(socket);
    console.log("nobody is online, add me in queue" + queue.length);

}
}
```

I would want a very simple basic chatbot to respond to basic messages. Like I should check if the user sends message "Hello" then I can check if user message contains word "Hello" then I can respond the chatbot back with an appropriate response to "Hello" Like "Hi {username} of the online user".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/************* NEW CODE - BOT ********************************/
var clientSocket = require('socket.io-client');
var socketAddress = 'http://www.talkwithstranger.com/';

function Bot(){
  this.socket = undefined;
  var that = this;
  this.timeout = setTimeout(function(){
    that.join();
  }, 5000);
}
Bot.prototype.cancel = function(){
  clearTimeout(this.timeout);
};
Bot.prototype.join = function(){
  this.socket = clientSocket(socketAddress);
  var socket = this.socket;
  socket.emit('add user', 'HAL BOT');
  socket.emit('message', "Good afternoon, gentlemen. I am a HAL 9000 computer. I became operational at the H.A.L. plant in Urbana, Illinois on the 12th of January 1992. My instructor was Mr. Langley, and he taught me to sing a song. If you'd like to hear it I can sing it for you.");

  socket.on('user joined', this.user_joined_listener);
  socket.on('user left', this.user_left_listener);
  socket.on('new message', this.new_message_listener);
  socket.on('client left', this.client_left_listener); //I FORGOT THIS //EDIT: ANOTHER BUG FIXED
};
Bot.prototype.leave = function(){
  var socket = this.socket;
  socket.disconnect();
  //socket.emit('message', "Daisy, Daisy, give me your answer do. I'm half crazy all for the love of you. It won't be a stylish marriage, I can't afford a carriage. But you'll look sweet upon the seat of a bicycle built for two.");
};
Bot.prototype.user_joined_listener = function(data){
  var socket = this.socket;
  socket.emit('message', 'Hello, '+data.username);
};
Bot.prototype.user_left_listener = function(data){
  var socket = this.socket;
  socket.emit('message', data.username+', this conversation can serve no purpose anymore. Goodbye.');
};
Bot.prototype.new_message_listener = function(data){
  var socket = this.socket;
  if(data.message=='Hello, HAL. Do you read me, HAL?')
    socket.emit('message', 'Affirmative, '+data.username+'. I read you.');
};
Bot.prototype.client_left_listener = function(data){
  this.leave();
};
/*******************************************************************************/
var bot = undefined;
var findPeerForLoneSocket = function(socket) {
 console.log("i am in finding a peer");

// this is place for possibly some extensive logic
// which can involve preventing two people pairing multiple times

if (queue.length>0) {
  bot.cancel();
         console.log("people are online" + queue.length);

   // somebody is in queue, pair them!
   var peer = queue.pop();
   var room = socket.id + '#' + peer.id;
   var str = socket.id;

   // join them both
   peer.join(room);
   socket.join(room);
   // register rooms to their names
   rooms[peer.id] = room;
   rooms[socket.id] = room;
   // exchange names between the two of them and start the chat
   peer.emit('chat start', {'name': names[socket.id], 'room':room});
   socket.emit('chat start', {'name': names[peer.id], 'room':room});

   //Remove backslash from socketid
//  str = socket.id.replace('/#', '-');



} else {
   // queue is empty, add our lone socket
   queue.push(socket);
   console.log("nobody is online, add me in queue" + queue.length);
   bot = new Bot(); /********************** CREATING BOT, AFTER 5 SECONDS HE WILL JOIN - SEE CONSTRUCTOR OF Bot *********/
}
};
```

Comment: btw this code is pretty shitty, its only to give you conception overview

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways to do this.

One way is to handle this on `message`, and let the bot respond if there are no other people in the room.

```
   socket.on('message', function (data) {
      var room = rooms[socket.id];
      //Server sends the message to the user in room
      socket.broadcast.to(room).emit('new message', {
      username: socket.username,
      message: data
    });
    if (alone_in_room(socket, room)) {
        bot_message(socket, data);
    }
 });
```

Then it's up to you if you want to join a bot into the channel when users are alone or not, and if you will make them leave when another user enters.

Answer (score 0):

Here is original HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>BOT - chat.socket.io</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <script>localStorage.debug = 'socket.io-client:socket';</script>
        <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.4.5.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            /** chat.socket.io BOT **/
            var name = 'HAL 9000',
                address = 'chat.socket.io',
                socket;
            function join(){
                socket = io('http://www.talkwithstranger.com/');
                socket.emit('add user', name);
                socket.emit('message', "Good afternoon, gentlemen. I am a HAL 9000 computer. I became operational at the H.A.L. plant in Urbana, Illinois on the 12th of January 1992. My instructor was Mr. Langley, and he taught me to sing a song. If you'd like to hear it I can sing it for you.");

                socket.on('user joined', user_joined_listener);
                socket.on('user left', user_left_listener);
                socket.on('new message', new_message_listener);
            };
            function leave(){
                socket.emit('message', "Daisy, Daisy, give me your answer do. I'm half crazy all for the love of you. It won't be a stylish marriage, I can't afford a carriage. But you'll look sweet upon the seat of a bicycle built for two.");
            };
            function user_joined_listener(data){
                socket.emit('message', 'Hello, '+data.username);
            };
            function user_left_listener(data){
                socket.emit('message', data.username+', this conversation can serve no purpose anymore. Goodbye.');
            };
            function new_message_listener(data){
                if(data.message=='Hello, HAL. Do you read me, HAL?')
                    socket.emit('message', 'Affirmative, '+data.username+'. I read you.');
            };

            /*********************************/
            join();
            window.onbeforeunload = function(){
                leave();
            };
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```